# First time access after facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

Is there any way that when user authenticate my app through Enhanced Auth Dialog, and gets redirected to canvas page, my canvas page knows its his first time visit?

Comment: You’d have to save the FB user id into your own database – then you can look it up if the user visiting your canvas page has been there before.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: Is there a way i know that user came to my app page from Enhanced Auth Dialog, by clicking Allow?

Answer (score 1):

Your may get the user id from facebook after the user redirected to canvas page:
Here is the example:

```
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config[‘secret’] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$app->user_id = $facebook->getUser();
```

After you obtain the user_id, you may save it in your database so that you can know whether the user is first time visit.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct and here is the code I use to check if they are a new user or a returning user. Then I insert them into the database if they are new.

```
// Get the app User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();


$seeif = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE fbid='$user' LIMIT 1"));

if ( $seeif == "1" ) {
// already exists
} else {
// insert new user
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (fbid) VALUES('$user' ) ") 
or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answers are correct, this might be more useful to you in the long run building your application.

Remember this relies on you having an open database connection as well as the facebook php sdk

```
// this brings back more info print_r($user)
$user = $facebook->api('/me');
$exists = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE fbid='" . $user['id'] . "'));

if ( $exists > 0) {
    // already exists
} else {
    // insert new user
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (fbid) VALUES('" . $user['id'] . "' ) ") or die(mysql_error());

    // do something else (post to timeline?)
    // look up facebook feed for more info on posting
try {
    // Post Message to feed.
    $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $msg);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    }
}
```